# Limit as $x \to 64$ of $\frac{\sqrt[6] x - 2}{\sqrt x - 8}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The question below is a question my teacher suggested for contest worthy of Grade 12 Calculus students. I don't need this answered right away but it would be nice if someone gave it a try

$$\lim_{x \to 64} \frac{\sqrt[6] x - 2}{\sqrt x - 8}$$

Comment: Please check your formula as I've typeset it and re-edit if needed.

Comment: Easily solved by L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Assuming it is correct then *Hint:* Write $\sqrt x - 8 = (x^{1/6} - 2)(x^{2/6} + 2x^{1/6} + 4)$

Comment: Try to convince yourself that $\sqrt[6]{x}\sqrt[6]{x}\sqrt[6]{x}=\sqrt{x}$. See what happens when you square both sides of this equation.

Answer (score 5):

Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ with $a=\sqrt[6\,]x$ and $b=2$.

Or use the extended mean value theorem.

Or its application, the rule of l'Hopital.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a little change $$\lim_{x \to 64} \frac{ x^{1/6} - 2}{x^{3/6} - 8}
=\lim_{y \to 2} \frac{ y - 2}{y^3 - 2^3}$$
then it is easy to use what LutzL has offered in a first line, so you get $y-2$ factorized and your limit become
$$\lim_{y \to 2} \frac{ 1}{y^2 +2y+ 2^2}$$
whhere you can easily substitute $y=2$ because now there no more division by zero, you should get there $\frac{1}{12}$.